# How to change color of navigation bar of CNContactPickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, contacts

I want to change color of navigation bar shows on `CNContactPickerViewController`.

I have tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
//  let searchController = UISearchController()
contactPicker.delegate = self
contactPicker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
//        UISearchBar.appearance().text = "SEARCH".localized
//        contactPicker.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
[CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey]
contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0 || phoneNumbers.@count > 0")

present(contactPicker, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the text in **navigationBar** just add these lines to **willConnectTo** method inside **SceneDelegate** file:

```
 UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent            = false
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor             = .orange
 UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor                = .yellow
 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes      = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple]
 UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.purple]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change naviagtion bar colors by:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .blue
```

this will change it for the whole app so you can change the color before showing the controller and change it back to original on the controller dismissing

Comment: i have use code but it changes searchbar background...

Comment: you can play with: `UISearchTextField.appearance()` and `UISearchBar.appearance()` until you get the result you want